# How to show .csv data file in a more visualized .html file?

Tags: python

Below is is my output .csv file. Is there a way to show the output in .html template file using python to show it in more visualized way?

```
Date,Text
2021-09-03,"['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'doing', 'well', 'now']"
2021-09-04,"['ABC', 'is', 'good']"
2021-09-15,['Done']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("read_file.csv")
a.to_html("Table.htm")
```

Another solution:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable



# open csv file
a = open("read_file.csv", 'r')
 
# read the csv file
a = a.readlines()
 
# Separating the Headers
l1 = a[0]
l1 = l1.split(',')
 
# headers for table
t = PrettyTable([l1[0], l1[1]])
 
# Adding the data
for i in range(1, len(a)) :
    t.add_row(a[i].split(','))
 
code = t.get_html_string()
html_file = open('Tablee.html', 'w')
html_file = html_file.write(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Matvey_coder3's answer that using the [prettytable](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/) module might be a good option. In addition the Python `csv` module could be used to read the data. Example below:

```
import csv
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import webbrowser

# Read CSV data.
with open("date_text.csv", 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    columns = next(reader)
    rows = [row for row in reader]

# Create HTML table from it.
tbl = PrettyTable(columns)
for row in rows:  # Add data to table.
    tbl.add_row(row)

with open('table.html', 'w') as html_file:
    html_file.write(tbl.get_html_string())

webbrowser.open('table.html', new=1)  # View result.
```

Here's how the `table.html` file looked when opened in my web browser:

[image: screenshot of file in web browser]